# Mediapipe pose detect the person inside the rectangle

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, mediapipe, pose-detection

So I've drawn a rectangle on a video and now I want to detect the person inside the rectangle with mediapipe pose and not the one mediapipe pose defaults to show if there are many people.

Can someone help me?
Thankyou!

Comment: Could you post your code in any place?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.